# how to import another razor component library js asset dynamically in blazor?

Tags: c#, razor, maui, blazor-webassembly, maui-blazor

I have two solution in VisualStudio and the directory tree struct look like these:

`BlazorRCL.Assets`

[image: BlazorRCL.Assets.dll]

`BlazorRCL.Demos`

[image: BlazorRCL.Demos]

And i try to import the `exampleJsInterop.js` into `BlazorRCL.Demo.UI` which is located in `BlazorRCL.Assets` like this code:

```
// counter.razor
@page "/counter"

@inject IJSRuntime Runtime;

<PageTitle>Counter</PageTitle>

<h1>Counter</h1>

<p role="status">Current count: @currentCount</p>

<button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="IncrementCount">Click me</button>

@code {
    private int currentCount = 0;
    private Lazy<Task<IJSObjectReference>> _exampleJs;

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        _exampleJs = new Lazy<Task<IJSObjectReference>>(Runtime.InvokeAsync<IJSObjectReference>("import", "./_content/BlazorRCL.Assets/exampleJsInterop.js").AsTask());
    }

    private async Task IncrementCount()
    {
        currentCount++;
        await new BlazorRCL.Assets.ExampleJsInterop(Runtime).Prompt(currentCount.ToString());
    }
}
```

But i got a 404 error when counter page initialized.

[image: 404 error]

And then i try to import and execute it by using `ExampleJsInterop` class in `IncrementCount` method and now i got an error in web console:

[image: web console]

The interesting thing is that it can correct import if i change my code like this:

```
// counter.razor
@page "/counter"

@inject IJSRuntime Runtime;

<PageTitle>Counter</PageTitle>

<h1>Counter</h1>

<p role="status">Current count: @currentCount</p>

<button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="IncrementCount">Click me</button>

@code {
    private int currentCount = 0;
    private Lazy<Task<IJSObjectReference>> _exampleJs;

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        _exampleJs = new Lazy<Task<IJSObjectReference>>(Runtime.InvokeAsync<IJSObjectReference>("import", "./_content/BlazorRCL.Demo.UI/exampleJsInterop.js").AsTask());
    }

    private async Task IncrementCount()
    {
        currentCount++;
    }
}
```

[image: success import]

Why can I only import Web Content for projects in the same solution?

How can I import Web Content from other razor component library projects?

I try to recreate solution,projects.
And try to ask Chat-GPT.
And try download other package in github and try to import it.
but seems that only i have this problem.
I try to upload my codes zip file but i don't know how to upload archives so if you need the code files to find more information then you can contact me to send you a email with archive.

Thanks guys!

---

P.S.

I confirm that i have referenced the `BlazorRCL.Assets.dll` in the `BlazorRCL.Demo.UI` project

Comment: Are you looking for the [Call JavaScript functions from .NET methods in ASP.NET Core Blazor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/javascript-interoperability/call-javascript-from-dotnet?view=aspnetcore-7.0#javascript-isolation-in-javascript-modules)?

Comment: @GuangyuBai-MSFT Hello! Thanks for your help, I think I have tried [this way](https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/aspnet/core/blazor/javascript-interoperability/?view=aspnetcore-7.0#load-a-script-from-an-external-javascript-file-js) in the article.I tried importing using the script tag or using JSRuntime to import， even the default example of ExampleJsInterop, which was automatically generated when creating the razor component library.This is works for me if the razor component library and the projects that import it are in a solution, but not in the two different solution

Comment: The two solutions belong to the different projects. You can not get the .js file from the different project. You can check the notes about [JavaScript isolation in JavaScript modules](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/javascript-interoperability/call-javascript-from-dotnet?view=aspnetcore-7.0#javascript-isolation-in-javascript-modules) for more information.

Comment: @GuangyuBai-MSFT Hello!  Thanks again for your help, I will read this article carefully again :)